# How to draw line or rectangle to Plane in code?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I create a Plane of 3D object in my scene, and also write a c# script as below with it. But the plane's color is not changed, still show white color, why? BTW, the plane use Mesh Renderer component.

```
private Texture2D drawTexture;
private Color[] buffer;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Texture2D mainTexture =
       (Texture2D)GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture;
    Color[] pixels = mainTexture.GetPixels();

    buffer = new Color[pixels.Length];
    pixels.CopyTo(buffer, 0);

    // Change pixel color of drawing area
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; ++i)
    {
        buffer.SetValue(Color.red, i);
    }

    // Update pixels of texture with changed pixels
    drawTexture = new Texture2D(mainTexture.width,
          mainTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
    drawTexture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
    drawTexture.SetPixels(buffer);
    drawTexture.Apply();
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = drawTexture;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you change the texture "by hand" in the editor? And what kind of material are you using?

Comment: Material is Default-Material, and its shader is Standard.

Comment: Why are you changing all pixels of the texture to a color instead of using the color property of the material shader?